# Problem using hibernate across JVMs

Tags: hibernate

My applicaton makes calls to a server which is clustered across 2 JVMs.
The requests can go to either servers.
I am using Spring with Hibernate for DB calls (for DB2 database). 
However, I have noticed that there no automatic locking mechanism from Hibernate across JVMs. I did implement locking mechanism through something like - query.setLockMode("myBo", LockMode.UPGRADE); But this does not seem to work across the JVMs.

Problem scenario:

First JVM selects the data for update (with LockMode.UPGRADE in place) from Table1. Before first JVM finishes update, second JVM also selects the data from Table1(which should not happen). First JVM finishes update successfully. But second JVM fails (Update is happening on the index key for Table1) with DuplicateKeyException.

Can somebody please suggest a solution for this?

Thanks
Radhika

Comment: Do second transaction select data with `LockMode.UPGRADE` too? Do second transaction select the same data as the first one?

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to the fact you have several JVMs. You could have the same scenario with two concurrent threads on the same JVM, because Hibernate doesn't do any locking at all. If you need locking, then use optimistic locks (using a version attribute), or use locks in the database (with LockMode.UPGRADE).

But both locking mechanisms will lead to exceptions : they're unavoidable once you have several parallel transactions working on the same data. You have to design your application (i.e. present error messages, implement retry mechanisms, etc.) with that in mind.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Will have to implement some error/exception handling logic for concurrent data access since Hibernate Locking is not taking an effect.